# Accessing the int value outside of the method

Tags: java

I have a method `A` in class `Test`, which generates a number `a` and `b`, heres the code for it:

```
public class Test
{
    int a,b;

    public void A()
    {
        a = currentMenu.getCurrentFocusedItem().getItemID();
        b = currentMenu.getMenuID();
        System.out.println("Inside A ()" + a  + " &&" + b);
    }

    public void B()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside B ()" + a  + " &&" + b);
    }
}
```

Now, I want to acces the `a` and `b` `int` values, into another method `B()`, in the same
     class file.
   Need some pointer

Comment: a = currentMenu.getCurrentFocusedItem().getItemID();
b = currentMenu.getMenuID();
System.out.println("Inside A ()" + a  + " &&" + b);

What this println gives?

Comment: Are you calling method A() before calling method B().

Comment: your current construction is bit risky, as `B()` can be invoked before `A()`, which leave you with unsetted values

Comment: a and b return the int value..lets say something like a= 12345 and b = 23456.and also the B() is called after A() method everytime..

Answer (score 1):

you can get the a and b values in `instance` initialization `block`

```
public class TestClass {
    int a,b;
    {
         a= 10;
         b =45;
    }

    public void A() {
        System.out.println("Inside A ()" + a + " &&" + b);
    }

    public void B() {
        System.out.println("Inside B ()" + a + " &&" + b);
    }

}
```

Using this method, you don't have to call your `A()` method for populating the values to be used in `B()`

Comment: What are you trying to do here by redefining a and b?

Comment: @JunedAhsan, thanks I didn't notice I was creating local variables

Comment: @JunedAhsan, improvising comments are always welcome :) I'm a learner. Will learn continuously

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with the same instance of the class `Test`, the value of `a` and `b` as set in method `A()` should still be visible in method `B()`.

So, the below would work:

```
Test test = new Test();

test.A();
test.B();
```

However, the below wouldn't

```
new Test().A();
new Test().B();
```

On a side note, methods in Java should always begin with a lowercase letter and use camelcase.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are trying to do is to get the current(and latest) value of a and b,
you could write 2 methods like

```
public int getA() {
    return currentMenu.getCurrentFocusedItem().getItemID();
}

public int getB() {
    return currentMenu.getMenuID();
}
```

and use these methods instead of calling A() to update the values of a,b and then accessing them again in method B.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too

```
  public void A()
{
    a = currentMenu.getCurrentFocusedItem().getItemID();
    b = currentMenu.getMenuID();
    System.out.println("Inside A ()" + a  + " &&" + b);
}
public void B()
{
    Test test=new Test();
    test.A();      // assign values for a and b
    System.out.println("Inside B ()" + a  + " &&" + b);
}
```